# Utilizando evento KeyPress com Regex

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, regex

Estou fazendo uma aplicação **C#** em **Windows Form** utilizando **.Net Framework 3.5**.
Nesta aplicação tenho um **textbox** para a entrada de CPF ou CNPJ.

Necessito que nesse campo possa ter somente números e caracteres de CPF/CNPJ (./-). Gostaria de validar esse campo no evento **KeyPress** utilizando **Regex**. Seria possível?

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de fazer a validação da `textbox` no `KeyPress`, faça no `Validating`. Assim evita a utilização do `Regex` a cada tecla premida.

```
private void textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Corra o regex aqui. Caso não seja o que pertende, cancele o evento.
    e.Cancel = true; // Cancela o evento e impede o utilizador de sair da textbox
}
```

Ao cancelar o evento, o utilizador fica impedido de tirar o foco da textbox e pode fazer aparecer um `tooltip` ou mudar a cor da `textbox` para indicar que existe um erro com o valor introduzido.

Comment: Omni, preciso que seja a cada tecla pressionada, por isso preciso que seja o evento KeyPress.

Comment: @andreguilherme posso perguntar porque tem de ser a cada key press? Já pensou em utilizar uma MaskedTextBox?

Comment: O boss quer assim :(

Comment: @andreguilherme não me cabe opinar sobre as decisões tomadas sem saber os motivos. De qualquer forma pode validar o campo na mesma no `KeyPress`, mas não vai evitar que o utilizador saia do campo por exemplo (pelo menos sem lógica adicional). E tal como mencionei, correr um regex a cada tecla tem custos. Só um detalhe que não é claro na sua pergunta, também quer saber como fazer o Regex?